# How to undelete mail message in iOS8

Tags: ios, mobile-mail

I can move a message from Trash to inbox, but is there a better way to undelete a message?

I find that when I go to the trash folder, it's really easy to mess up and delete rather than move.

I've also tried using the Shake gesture. I get mixed results. Sometimes that works, often not.